# mongoose unique not work in subitem in object even if i use addToSet

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

i try to make my schema work but :(

```
Schema({
  name: String
  text: [
    {
      name: String,
      language: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

what i do if i want they cant add 2 text with same language ??

```
let texte = [
    { name: "first", language: "English" },
    { name: "duplicate", language: "English" }
  ];
  newData.text.addToSet(texte[0]);
  newData.text.addToSet(texte[1]);
  newData.text.addToSet(texte[1]);
```

if I push duplicate text in same language I don't get error

```
    {
  "_id": "5c6aff3e6c895637094427d7",
  "text": [
    {
      "_id": "5c6aff3e6c895637094427d8",
      "name": "first",
      "language": "English"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5c6aff3e6c895637094427d9",
      "name": "duplicate",
      "language": "English"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5c6aff3e6c895637094427da",
      "name": "duplicate",
      "language": "English"
    },
  ],
  "name": "test"
}
```

i hope there is a way for it :(

Answer (score 0):

Setting unique to true does not check for duplicate data in the database before creating or updating. You have to check that yourself before creating or updating documents. Setting unique to true adds an unique index for that field in mongodb. Its usage is not what you think.

What you can do is run a query first to check if a document already exists with the  field you want to be unique.

```
Colection.find({ "text.name": "duplicate", "text.language": "English" })
 .then(doc => {
   if(doc) {
     // handle duplicate case

   } else {
    // create new

   }
 })
```

Or if you want to validate data before its saved in database, you can use a validation library like [JOI](https://github.com/hapijs/joi). This will handle most of your use cases for handling schema validation.